# SNR measurement

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, snr

I am using QPSK modulation for a BER of $10^{-6}$ at $\text{SNR}=E_b/N_0=10 \ \rm dB$.

- If my data rate is $5 \ \rm kbps$ then
  $$S/N_0 = 10\log_{10}(5000)+10 = 47\  \rm dB$$
- And if my RF section has a filter of bandwidth $100\ \rm kHz$ and noise filter of $2\ \rm dB$ then noise floor becomes $$-172+10\log_{10}(100000)+2= -120\ \rm dB$$

1. So should the signal level of $-110\ \rm dB$ be OK for BER of $10^{-6}$?
2. I was trying to measure SNR on spectrum analyzer. I put RBW as $100 \rm Hz$. So if $S/N= 38\ \rm dB$ then $S/N_0= 58 \ \rm dB$ ?  Should this be better that 47dB calculated above?

Comment: Can you try to structure your questio a little better? I really don't understand what you're asking, and part of that is because I can't see where one sentence ends and the next starts.

Comment: Also: **You've received at least 7 answers already**, and accepted or voted on none. A lot of these answers were pretty high-effort, and you'll need to engange with the community if you want it to persist in offering answers.  *I will certainly not spend any time trying to decipher your question until you start interacting with those who work hard to write answers.* (this is **not** the first time this has been pointed out to you; your questions are low-effort, and you don't give back.)

Comment: I have edited the question. please let me know if anybody can help me out if my understanding is OK?